# @TestNg [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, spring-data, testng, testng-eclipse

When I was running a test ng method using the '*@Test*' annotation, we got an exception and the test was not running.

TestNG class

```
package testNGtest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class loginlogout {

public WebDriver driver;
String driverPath = "D:\\chromedriver.exe";
public String BaseURL = "https://xxxx.com/login";
    @Test
    public String loginPage() {               
    
        System.out.println(BaseURL);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
        driver= new ChromeDriver();     
        driver.get(BaseURL);
        String currentUrl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
        Assert.assertTrue(currentUrl.contains("/login"));
        return "URL is found";
     }
}
```

when i am running this test as testNG Test, it shows [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run. But when i am just run only with

```
System.out.println(BaseURL);
```

it displaying the BaseURL, but when adding the rest of the code, shows no tests found. I am using chrome browser version 91.0.4472.124 and chrome driver version i have downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=91.0.4472.101/ and saved it to my D drive. And i have added two jar files 'client-combined-3.141.59.jar and client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar' as Referenced libraries in my Project. As a test result, i can see the following

This console error message

```
[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
  Options:
    -alwaysrunlisteners
      Should MethodInvocation Listeners be run even for skipped methods
      Default: true
    -configfailurepolicy
      Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
    -d
      Output directory
    -dataproviderthreadcount
      Number of threads to use when running data providers
    -dependencyinjectorfactory
      The dependency injector factory implementation that TestNG should use.
    -excludegroups
      Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
    -failwheneverythingskipped
      Should TestNG fail execution if all tests were skipped and nothing was 
      run. 
      Default: false
    -groups
      Comma-separated list of group names to be run
    -junit
      JUnit mode
      Default: false
    -listener
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener 
      or ISuiteListener
    -methods
      Comma separated of test methods
      Default: []
    -methodselectors
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
    -mixed
      Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with 
      appropriate runner
      Default: false
    -objectfactory
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing 
      ITestRunnerFactory 
    -parallel
      Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
      Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none, true, false]
    -port
      The port
    -reporter
      Extended configuration for custom report listener
    -spilistenerstoskip
      Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be 
      skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
      Default: <empty string>
    -suitename
      Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or 
      source code
    -suitethreadpoolsize
      Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
      Default: 1
    -testclass
      The list of test classes
    -testjar
      A jar file containing the tests
    -testname
      Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source 
      code 
    -testnames
      The list of test names to run
    -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
      The factory used to create tests
    -threadcount
      Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
    -threadpoolfactoryclass
      The threadpool executor factory implementation that TestNG should use.
    -usedefaultlisteners
      Whether to use the default listeners
      Default: true
    -log, -verbose
      Level of verbosity
    -xmlpathinjar
      The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if 
      -testjar was specified)
      Default: testng.xml
```

I want to run my test which is using testNg without any error or exception for above code.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add details around: (1) How are you running your test (IDE/Build tool) (2) Share the complete stacktrace from the console

Answer (score 0):

We have ways to solve the above bug.

1. If your test ng method has a non-void return type[Not void].
   If we remove the non-void return type for the test method.
2. Instead of removing the non-void return type we can add a line to the testng.xml file that accepts any return type for testNg methods.
   Line